# Why doesn't this generate the lucky numbers?

Tags: c#, iteration, generator, sequences

I am trying to write a function which generates the [lucky numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucky_number),

```
static IEnumerable<int> LuckyNumbers()
{
  IEnumerable<int> luckyNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue);
  int counter = 1;
  while (true)
  {
    int number = luckyNumbers.ElementAt(counter++);
    yield return number;
    luckyNumbers = luckyNumbers.Where((_, index) => (index + 1) % number != 0);
  }
}
```

but this generates:

```
2,5,7,11,13,17,21,...
```

which are not the lucky numbers.

Why doesn't my code work? I am trying to:

1. start with all the natural numbers:

   ```
   IEnumerable<int> luckyNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue);
   int counter = 1;
   ```
2. iterate through them and return the next lucky number:

   ```
   while (true)
   {
     int number = luckyNumbers.ElementAt(counter++);
     yield return number;
   ```
3. remove all `n`th numbers from the sequence:

   ```
   luckyNumbers = luckyNumbers.Where((_, index) => (index + 1) % number != 0);
   ```

I don't see why this doesn't work as I intend.

Comment: Bear in mind that each time you perform step 3, you're ending up with a new sequence. Now, are you certain that you want element `counter` from that new sequence? Try going through it all on a piece of paper...

Comment: @JonSkeet I am pretty sure, I thought I am meant to be taking the next element from the previous generation of the sequence every time. But I can try it on paper.

Comment: Given that wikipedia has a worked example, I suggest you follow that while debugging. First issue I note is that you're starting with the second element because you've got `counter = 1` rather than `counter = 0`. That means you'll never return 1, which is meant to be a lucky number.

Comment: The algorithm is a bit strange. For the first number, `1` is taken and every `2nd` element is erased. For all following numbers, the number taken and the number of steps towards the next erased number equals. So I guess you have to handle `1` specially before going into the actual re-occuring algorithm form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why your code does not work:

1. Collections in programming are zero-indexed. This is why the first number you generate is 2, because its the number with index 1. You should rather initialize `counter` to 0.
2. I think you initialized counter to `1` to avoid canceling the 1-th number out of the sequence (which will effectively kill all numbers and therefore taking the element at a given position is doomed to fail). The problem lies in the definition of the lucky numbers here: While the first lucky number is 1, the first iteration is to strike every *second* number. So you have to take `Math.Min(number, 2)`.

Finally, you arrive at the following:

```
    static IEnumerable<int> LuckyNumbers()
    {
        IEnumerable<int> luckyNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, int.MaxValue);
        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            int number = luckyNumbers.ElementAt(counter++);
            yield return number;
            int moduloCheck = Math.Max(number, 2);
            luckyNumbers = luckyNumbers.Where((_, index) => (index + 1) % moduloCheck != 0);
        }
    }
```

From a performance perspective, though, I think the solution is horrible for large numbers as you will repeatedly check the first numbers forever at the `ElementAt`. Because a where-expression is not indexable, this will always start checking each number for several where conditions. The good thing though is that you can simply use it as `LuckyNumbers().Take(n)` to get the first `n` lucky numbers.

Comment: "I think you initialized counter to 1 to avoid canceling the 1-th number out of the sequence " – this is true.